# Change variable depending on how much you scroll

Tags: javascript, scroll

I would like to make a JS page with a variable `$depth`. And this variable should be constantly adjusted, depending on how much pixels you've scrolled down to the pag.

But I have not a single clue how to write this. Is there anyone with some experience concerning this situation, or any clues how to tackle this issue?

Comment: You realise that PHP runs on the server?  So you're asking for a mechanism which would notify the server every time the user scrolled the page in their browser?

Comment: Hm, ok. That's right. I forgot. Javascript is the way to go, I guess. No?

Comment: What is the task you wish to accomplish?

Comment: To get the amount of pixels a user has scrolled down my page...

Comment: But for what purpose?  If you weren't sure whether you needed PHP or JS, it sounds like the goal isn't terribly clear, in which case it may not be possible to give a good answer until we've clarified the goal.

Comment: I know PHP runs on a server, but I've been coding for 20u in PHP, so hence the mistake :) But I think the answer of Larsenal would do the trick...

Answer (score 1):

Easy to do with JQuery:

```
$(window).scroll(function(e) {
    var position = $(this).scrollTop();
}
```